# How can I separate glued wooden flooring planks?

Tags: joints

I have had a 20mm thick wooden floor laid and due to a plumbing problem have to take it up again and re-lay. The fixer glued the tongue and groove together with PVA which I now need to separate, clean and re-fix. There is about 50square metres of this flooring.

Comment: Welcome to [woodworking.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that not only is this a Question & Answer site (where it's expected that you actually ask a question), but you'll learn that the more details you can provide us, the better. Is this a real wood floor or a laminate/vinyl type floor? How long ago was the floor installed?  You can [edit] your question to update it. It's unlikely you'll be able to "unglue" the floor, but this info will help inform an answer about how to pull it up and repair it afterwards.

Comment: Ouch!  I assume this is solid wood (laminate /engineered wood tends to be thinner and not really T&G).  What is lying on (joists, another wooden floor, concrete, battens on concrete, etc.)?  How is it attached to whatever it is lying on (glued, nailed, just floating)?  Whereabouts is the plumbing issue?  Do the pipes run parallel to the planks, or cross-wise.  Please edit your question to provide these details.

Comment: What's your plumbing problem? This could be a XY problem. Perhaps there is a solution which does not involve breaking up your floor. Plumbers can be very creative.

Comment: It is possible to remove and replace planks in the middle of a wooden floor. The guy I hired to do that used a router. Most likely you don't need to remove the entire floor.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully separated wooden furniture glued with PVA using a heat-gun - but it probably works only for thinner pieces - and you have to use lower setting, otherwise you'll not only burn the wood, but the wood may also break down and release pitch or tar, which is definitelly not a good thing. Perhaps try with the same glue on some offcuts of the same/similar wood to see if it works and how high you can go with the temperature..

Answer (score 0):

PVA can be dissolved with vinegar ("cleaning/industrial vinegar", not the cooking stuff).
And heating the vinegar makes it work even better.
(See also [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/remove-3-maybe-4-decades-old-pva-glue-from-lego/16328#16328) question on the Bricks StackExchange about separating Lego bricks glued together with PVA.)

Unfortunately it would soak (and maybe warp) the wood.
And probably cause serious discoloration as well.
So the flooring might be a write-off anyway...

So to me that would be a last resort.

If you have access from below that floor (another floor or basement below it?) it may be better (and cheaper) to access the plumbing from below, even if you have to cut open the ceiling to get at it.
Re-doing a drywall or plaster ceiling would most likely be cheaper than a new hardwood floor.